# PHP file_get_contents, execute the PHP on the included file before include

Tags: php, html, file-get-contents

Currently I use the file_get_contents command to include the html of a file. Now I added PHP to it and it is causing a problem. The PHP is being read as html and thus not executed. How can I retrieve the file content with the PHP executed?

Oh and I need the content in a tring. So include doesn't work in this case I believe, right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
ob_start();
include 'file_to_include.php';
$contents = ob_get_clean();
```

The content of the included file (with PHP being executed) is in `$contents`.

Comment: You could use [`ob_get_flush()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-flush.php) and eliminate the last function.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I added it to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: I tried this out. It might put the include in the string as asked, but it also includes the file in the area where the include is set. This cannot be allowed to happen. Any ideas?

Comment: I edited your answer, the change should be seen soon. ob_get_clean was what i was looking for ;)